# Describe someone who is erroneously biased in thinking their first try is correct

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

A student needs to write a paper in English

He had a brilliant moment of inspiration and wrote down his idea word-for-word from his thoughts onto paper

When he got his paper back he was shocked to find out he got an average mark. He falsely believed  he will get top marks.

He believed writing down his words verbatim, word-for-word from his thoughts, the writing  would be the most brilliant as it is the original version. However if only he reviewed it to improve it, he would have gotten a much better mark.

His teacher finds students often have this bias.

What word(s) would one use to describe him or his behavior where he was erroneously biased in thinking his first try is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*lacking insight*

> Insight is a psychological term that attempts to describe the process in problem solving when a previously unsolvable puzzle becomes suddenly clear and obvious. Often this transition from not understanding to spontaneous comprehension is accompanied by an exclamation of joy or satisfaction, an Aha! moment. A person utilizing insight to solve a problem is able to give accurate, discrete, all-or-nothing type responses, whereas **individuals not using the insight process are more likely to produce partial, incomplete responses.** –[Eureka effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect)

---

Having a *cognitive bias*.

> A cognitive bias refers to a systematic pattern of deviation from norm or rationality in judgment, whereby inferences about other people and situations may be drawn in an illogical fashion. Individuals create their own "subjective social reality" from their perception of the input. An individual's construction of social reality, not the objective input, may dictate their behaviour in the social world. Thus, cognitive biases may sometimes lead to perceptual distortion, inaccurate judgment, illogical interpretation, or what is broadly called irrationality.
>
> Some cognitive biases are presumably adaptive. Cognitive biases may lead to more effective actions in a given context. Furthermore, cognitive biases enable faster decisions when timeliness is more valuable than accuracy, as illustrated in heuristics. Other cognitive biases are a "by-product" of human processing limitations, resulting from a lack of appropriate mental mechanisms (bounded rationality), or simply from a **limited capacity for information processing**. –[Cognitive bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias)

I thought I was doing this myself with my first offering, until I got to the last line of my second one. Then again, if I'm answering a question with *cognitive bias*, it is almost assuredly a dupe (assuming I'm correct), but that would put me back at square one because I think that everything these days is a duplicate question in one way or another... which would mean that I *lack insight due to cognitive bias*. This results in what is known on the internet as *"shit posting"*.

Answer (score 4):

*hubris*

> Dictionary Definition:-
>   excessive pride or self-confidence.

*His belief that he could get it right the very first time is pure hubris.*

Answer (score 2):

I'd say **cocksure**
                                                            cock·sure

\ˈkäk-ˈshu̇r\

adjective

: having or showing confidence in a way that is annoying to other people

Full Definition

1 : feeling perfect assurance sometimes on inadequate grounds 2 : marked by overconfidence or presumptuousness :

Answer (score 1):

Magical thinking -

> Believing that the laws of physics, economics, or the laws of cause and effect, don't apply to you. Believing in miracles or believing that wishful thinking or sheer will alone can cause the outcome you are hoping for are examples of magical thinking, as are appeals to paranormal or supernatural phenomena. Don't let optimism exceed the bounds of reality. Hope is not a strategy.

http://www.emotionalcompetency.com/distortions.htm